# Write custom H2 DB function Java

Tags: spring-boot, db2, ibatis, h2db

I am trying to run the below code using H2DB (via junit test), while doing so i get error message as below. I understand that, there are no function available as "days" in H2. So i am trying to write a custom function, but it does not work out, can any one help on writing this function.

SQLBuilder class code:

```
public String dummy() {
        return new StringBuilder(new SQL() {
            {
                SELECT("date(CREATE_TMS)");
                SELECT("CASE WHEN date(CREATE_TMS) >= (CURRENT DATE - cast('1' AS integer) days) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END NEW_B");
                FROM("Q.DUMMY");
            }
        }.toString().concat(" FOR READ ONLY WITH UR")).toString();
    }
```

Error message:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT DATE(CREATE_TMS), CASE WHEN DATE(CREATE_TMS) >= (CURRENT DATE - CAST('1' AS INTEGER) DAYS[*]) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END NEW_BILLING
FROM Q.DUMMY FOR READ ONLY WITH UR "; expected "[, ::, *, /, %, +, -, ||, ~, !~, NOT, LIKE, ILIKE, REGEXP, IS, IN, BETWEEN, AND, OR, ,, )"; SQL statement:
SELECT date(CREATE_TMS), CASE WHEN date(CREATE_TMS) >= (CURRENT DATE - cast('1' AS integer) days) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END NEW_BILLING
FROM Q.DUMMY FOR READ ONLY WITH UR [42001-199]
```

For some reason **days** are converted to **DAYS[*]**, we can see that in error message.

Customer method i tried in schema-db2.sql:

```
drop ALIAS if exists days; 
CREATE ALIAS days as '
import java.lang.String;
@CODE
java.lang.String days() throws Exception { 
  return "days";
} 
';
```

applicaiton.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false;Mode=DB2
```

Comment: this code worked for me
`drop ALIAS if exists days; 
CREATE ALIAS days as '
import java.lang.String;
@CODE
java.lang.String days() throws Exception { 
  return "days";
} 
';`

Answer (score 0):

`DAYS` is not a function and is not a something that other databases support. Db2 also uses non-standard interval literals.

If you can build H2 from its current sources, you can use `cast('1' AS integer) day` in it (not the day**s**) and such construction is also supported by Db2. You can also simply use `1 DAY`, it is supported by current H2 and Db2 too.

`(CURRENT_DAY - 1 DAY)`

Sources of H2 are available on GitHub:

https://github.com/h2database/h2database

Building instructions are here:

https://h2database.com/html/build.html#building

You need a `jar` target.

To compile H2 from the current sources you need JDK 8, 9, 10, 11, or 12. Compiled jar will be compatible with more recent versions.

Comment: I had already tested with "day" instead of "days" it does not work, it throws same kind of error. As well "cast('1' AS integer) days" 1 is not constant, here a column name will come (dynamic value).

Comment: You need to build H2 from the current sources, neither 1.4.199 nor 1.4.200 support such expression.

Comment: I see 1.4.200 as latest jar for H2 from maven central repo. can you please tell about "H2 from current sources"

Comment: You need to download sources from GitHub and compile them by yourself as described in the documentation (see links in my answer).